# Rails: expose javascript object for polling by remote dashboard

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, highcharts, geckoboard

I'd like to expose a payload like this from my Rails app that can be polled by an external dashboard to build a chart of widget sales over time:

```
{
  chart: {
    style: {
      color: "#b9bbbb"
    },
    renderTo: "container",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    lineColor: "rgba(35,37,38,100)",
    plotShadow: false
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  title: {
    style: {
      color: "#b9bbbb"
    },
    text: "Weekly Widgets Sold"
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ["Dec 1", "Dec 2", "Dec 3", "Dec 4", "Dec 5", "Dec 6", "Dec 7", "Dec 8", "Dec 9"]
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      style: {
        color: "#b9bbbb"
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    color: "#108ec5",
    name: "Widgets Sold",
    data: [17, 22, 24, 24, 20, 14, 8, 2]
  }, ]
}
```

Most Geckoboard polling is done via JSON but for Highcharts they want "Javascript". I'm not sure the Rails way to expose Javascript. I feel this wants to be a *view* but I'm not sure how and where to build this object.

Hoping for an example or sage words of advice.

Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you cannot return JSON in rails? Maybe better is use [this wrapper](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts)